# HTTP error 400 occurs when Winforms calls Web API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, asp.net-web-api

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to develop a Winforms program, and Visual Studio reported a http 400 error when calling Web API.

Here is the code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.Method = "POST";
request. Referer = Referer;

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);

request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

Stream myResponseStream = request.GetRequestStream();

myResponseStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse(); //error
```

Error:

> System.Net.WebException: "Theremoteserver returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

This is my Web API controller:

```
 [Route("api/MyWebApi")]
 [ApiController]
 public class MyWebApiController : ControllerBase
 {
     private readonly ILogger<MyWebApiController> _logger;

     public MyWebApiController(ILogger<MyWebApiController> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }

     [HttpPost("[action]")]
     public IActionResult SayHello([FromBody] UserModel model)
     {
         if (model.pwd != "1")
         {
             object obj = new
             {
                 code = "0",
                 msg = "Request failed"
             };

             return new JsonResult(obj);
             //return new BadRequestResult();
         }
         else
         {
             object obj = new
             {
                 code = "1",
                 msg = "Request successful"
             };

             return new JsonResult(obj);
         }
     }
 }
```

I tried this [ASP.NET Web Api HttpResponseException 400 (Bad Request) Hijacked by IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985327/asp-net-web-api-httpresponseexception-400-bad-request-hijacked-by-iis) and it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me?

Comment: How is your data look like ? Your sample code does not contain data that you are posting.

Comment: The data is determined as a string type parameter in the post static method, I don't think there is anything special about it

Comment: @BilinVance Can you tell me in detail what is the data you passed in? An example can be given to illustrate. The issue is likely to be there

Comment: Do you mean the transmitted data is wrong?

Comment: @BilinVance Yes, because I noticed that your ContentType is application/json. Then you cannot use string or int when passing data, you need to maintain the consistency of the data type.
You can refer to [How to Turn a C# Object Into a JSON String in .NET?](https://code-maze.com/csharp-object-into-json-string-dotnet/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have solved it. As you said, there is a problem with the type of the transmitted data. I have already processed the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I noticed that your ContentType is application/json. Then you cannot use string or int when passing data, you need to maintain the consistency of the data type. You can refer to [How to Turn a C# Object Into a JSON String in .NET](https://code-maze.com/csharp-object-into-json-string-dotnet/)?